# How to Use Shims / Stub for private method and readonly properties (getter)

Tags: c#, get, readonly

How to use Shim context to override the private method and read-only properties.
like to use

```
public string FullName {
get {
return "First" + "Last";
}
}
```

Also is there any requirement to instantiate Component under test to execute the Shim context results.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is this anything of use to you?

```
Class A {
    public virtual string FullName {get {"First" + "Last",}}
}

ClassB : ClassA {
    public override string FullName {get {"My new name";} }
}
```

Instead you could also use a private backing-field that you set within the constructor of `ClassB` appropriately. To override a private method is not possible, only protected, internals or public members are.

Comment: I was asking about in reference of fakes, shims for unit test a private method or read only property.

Comment: @Einstine : So why isn't this info *in your question*?

Answer (score 1):

It worked to access a readonly property through shims context

```
Fakes.ShimCustomer.AllInstances.FullNameGet = (cust) => 
                {
                    return "Hello World";
                };
```

Any call from UnitTest to above property will output as "Hello World"

Thanks.